# To take off the Transparency features in Yosemite

Tags: macos

I have the newest Macbook Air with maximum flash memory and processor power. 
Still, the search functionality lacks i.e. there is a time gap when hitting a button and getting the result in Finder. 
No such gap exists in Terminal.

**How can you take of the new features of Transparency and others which can make my Yosemite faster?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open up **System Preferences**.
2. Click on **Accessibility**.
3. Place a checkmark next to **Reduce Transparency**.

[How to Improve OS X Yosemite Performance](http://www.gottabemobile.com/2014/10/28/how-to-improve-os-x-yosemite-performance/)